# Calculating volume using integration

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

I'm trying to calculate the volume of $(a,b,c) \in [0,1]^3$ such that $b^2 \geq 4ac$. It should be $\frac{5}{36}+\frac16 \log(2)$ but I can't figure out how to calculate this. I arrive at $\frac19$ at one calculation and $\infty$ at another, so certainly I'm doing something wrong. Any ideas?

My calculation is certainly wrong, but I tried the following to calculate the volume, since we have $\sqrt{4xz}<y<1$ and  $xz<\frac14$ and thus $x<\frac{1}{4z}$:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
& & \int_{0}^{1} \int_{\sqrt{4xz}}^{1} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{4z}}1\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z \\ & = & \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{4z}}(1-\sqrt{4xz})\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}z\\ & = & \int_{0}^{1}\left[x-\frac{1}{4z}(4xz)^{3/2}\frac23\right]_0^{1/(4z)}\mathrm{d}z\\ & =  & \int_{0}^{1}\left[\frac{1}{4z}-\frac{1}{4z}\frac23\right]\mathrm{d}z\\ & = & \frac{1}{12} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z}\\ & = & +\infty \end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: please write down your calculation so we can check it :)

Comment: Your latex error is somewhere near the latest `frac`.

Comment: Thanks, I have no access to computer right now so I couldn't see live what was going on. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A naive approach would tell you that the desired volume is given by $$\int^1_0 \int^{1/4a}_0 \int_{\sqrt{4ac}}^1 db \, dc \, da.$$ However, the area you need to integrate in the $ac$-plane is given by $ac \le 1/4$ and $0 \le a, c \le 1$. Now if $a \le 1/4$. Then any $c$ will do, so we can have $0 \le c \le 1$. If $a \ge 1/4$, then we need to require $c \le 1/4a$. Thus the correct volume is $$\int^{1/4}_0 \int^{1}_0 \int_{\sqrt{4ac}}^1 db \, dc \, da + \int^1_{1/4} \int^{1/4a}_0 \int_{\sqrt{4ac}}^1 db \, dc \, da.$$ Notice that this averts the singularity at $a = 0$. However, I believe you have a typo in your answer: I believe the first term should be $5/36$ rather than $5/32$ (of course it is possible I made an algebra mistake).

Comment: You're right about the typo, I'll correct that one!

Comment: I worked out your approach and I arrive at the same solution. Also, I understand why my approach is wrong. So many thanks! :)